# ActiveRecord: How to "select where in" on a has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Word object that has_many Categories through WordCategories

I want to get a list of words that have a relationship with the passed category ids.

In sql i would write

```
select * from words where category_id = (1,2,3,4)
```

Is it possible to do this but still bring back Word objects as a result?

**edit**

My example above is incorrect. I have a 3 Models,

- Word
- Category
- Dictionary

Word has many dictionaries, and categories through dictionaries
Category has many dictionaries, and words through dictionaries
Dictionary belongs to Word and Dictionary

Comment: If `Words` has_many `Categories` then `word_id` field would be present in `categories`. So, What is `category_id` in the question? Can you share the models.

Comment: @KirtiThorat - you are correct. I have an error in my example. I actually have the relations routing through a table called dictionaries. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the three models as follows:

```
Word.joins(word_categories: :category).where(category: { id: [1, 2, 3, 4] })
```

or join `word` and `word_categories` and use `word_categories.category_id` in the where clause as:

```
Word.joins(:word_categories).where(word_categories: { category_id: [1, 2, 3, 4] })
```

Comment: This looks to be the most optimized way (and it works). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord's `where` can take an array of IDs and search against that:

```
def self.with_category_ids(category_ids_array)
  where(:category_id => category_ids_array)
end
```

Would be a class method that returns all `Word` objects that have a `category_id` which is "`in`" `category_ids_array`.